# What's the difference between ContentObservable and DataSetObservable?

Tags: android, design-patterns

They both inherit from Observable. And their functions do not differ by much, why not provide only a single class?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from code sources, DataSetObservable is sending notifications to a list of `DataSetObserver` objects, while ContentObservable is sending notifications to a list of  `ContentObserver` objects

See sources:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/database/DataSetObservable.java

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/database/ContentObservable.java